# Getting 404 error in servlet Programming

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

While I am doing Servlet program I am getting 404 error.The problem is that from my welcome page the action is going wrong.After clicking submit button its redirecting to

```
http://localhost:7002/fs
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:7002/LoginApp/fs
```

Below is my web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>FirstServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.csscorp.servlets.FirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/fs</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please provide the solution.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here is my html page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login App</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/fs" method = "post">
UserName : <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
PassWord : <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'After clicking submit button its redirecting to' - so please show your submit button (the code including the HTML form).

Comment: updated my question with html form

Answer (score 4):

Your form's action is `/fs`. That is an absolute path pointing to `/fs`, and not to `/LoginApp/fs` as you want it to be. So, either use a relative path:

```
<form action="fs" method = "post">
```

or, better, use [the JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to generate an absolute path without hard-coding the context path (`/LoginApp`) of your application:

```
<form action="<c:url value='/fs' />" method = "post">
```